# Mysql Decimal division automatically round up

Tags: mysql, decimal

My Function is

```
DELIMITER $$;
CREATE FUNCTION get_approved_leaves(f_date date, t_date date,
                                    emp_id bigint, ltp_id int) 
RETURNS INT NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE leaves_taken decimal(10,3) DEFAULT 0.000;  

    SELECT  SUM(eld_first+eld_second)/2
    INTO  leaves_taken
    FROM  erp_apply_leaves, erp_employee_leave_debts
    WHERE  al_fk_employees = emp_id
      AND  al_from >= f_date
      AND  al_to <= t_date
      AND  al_fk_leave_type = ltp_id
      AND  eld_fk_apply_leaves = al_id
      AND  al_status = 101;

    RETURN leaves_taken;
END $$;
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call

```
SELECT get_approved_leaves('2017-01-01','2017-12-31',18, 5) as debted
    FROM `erp_employee_leave_debts` WHERE 1
```

It gives the out put : 20

But here SUM(eld_first+eld_second) = 39. So I need to get the output =  19.5

Comment: Change `RETURNS INT` to `RETURNS DECIMAL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function definition is expecting an `INT` as return value.

And as you are returning `leaves_taken` value, which is of type `DECIMAL(10,3)`,
SQL Engine is converting it to nearest `INTEGER` value, to match the return type, and returning.

If you want to keep the original value, better you change the return type of the function.

**Example is given below**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION 
       get_approved_leaves(  f_date date, t_date date
                           , emp_id bigint, ltp_id int ) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,3) NOT DETERMINISTIC
```